# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' [TypeError]

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, integer

I am currently learning Python so I have no idea what is going on.

```py
    # Given N, Amount of money in the house. Adjacent houses can't be stolen. Find the max amount that can be stolen
    # 6,7,1,30,8,2,4
    numbers = input()
    n = numbers.split(",")
    t = numbers.count(",")
    def rob(nums, i):
        if i <= 0:
            return 0
        return max(rob(nums, i-2) + nums[i], rob(nums, i-1))
    print(rob(n, t))
```

When I run the program, entering in numbers for Num and I, it returns this:

```py
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Everything in `nums` is a string... you need to convert them to integer... Also... `t` is fairly redundant... you might as well just use `t = len(n)`... - although it doesn't look like you actually really need that anyway

Comment: @JonClements how do i make "nums" into an integer because when i try "return max(rob(int(nums), i-2) + int(nums[i],) rob(int(nums), i-1))" it replys with "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'"

Comment: A quick "how do I convert a list of strings to numbers in Python" throws up: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-converting-all-strings-in-list-to-integers/

Comment: @JonClements i added
"def rob(nums, i):
    nums = [int(i) for i in nums]
    if i <= 0:
        return 0
    return max(rob(nums, i-2) + nums[i], rob(nums, i-1))
print(rob(n, t))"
but it says "IndexError: list index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

The values in the n array are of type `'str'`, not `'int'`. This is because the `.split` method returns type `'str'` You need to convert them to `'int'` in order to do the mathematical operations as you intend. Something like this:

```
n = [int(val) for val in n]
```

Put this after the line where n is initialized.

Comment: it says "IndexError: list index out of range" after i added what u said on the next line from "n = numbers.split(",")"

Comment: This comes from 'nums[i]'. When you first call rob, i is equal to t, which is the length of n or nums. As lists use 0-based indexing, nums[len(nums)] does not exist. The last element in nums is at element t-1, i.e. nums[t]. Perhaps using 'nums[i-1]' might solve this error. However, with the code as it is right now, this would also lead to problems when i eventually becomes 0 and you try to access nums[-1]. The logic probably needs rethinking, keeping in mind 0-based indexing of lists.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the type error, you need to do as follows in the return line:

```
return max(rob(nums, i-2) + int(nums[i]), rob(nums, i-1))
```

The problem is that you are adding the return value of `rob(nums, i-2)` to the value `nums[i]` which is a string, and addition of an int to string is undefined. Note that the split function returns a list of strings (which is what `n` is in your code).

Furthermore, I know you were not asking about whether the algorithm works or not, but for input `30,1,1,30` your code outputs `31`, but the max that can be stolen is `60`.